# Sending password reset link to users

Tags: c#, passwords

I am coding a link sent by email for users to reset their password. I want this link keep two parameters "send date" and "user id". so it may looks like

```
www.resetpassword.aspx?senddate="..."&userid="..."
```

I think these parameters should be encrypted and what I am wondering is that is it necessary to encrypt by some complicated two way algorithm or I can just convert the ASCII string to hex code.

Should I let users see there are send date and user id in the link? is there any general standard to do this?

Comment: ASCII to hex isn't encryption. It doesn't add any security at all. Your scheme is a bad idea in general. I'd create a random token, store it in the db, and use it to verify that this link is valid. In your current scheme any user can reset anybodies password, by just substituting somebody else's UserId. If possible use a pre-built library to do this.

Comment: **Use ASP.Net Forms Auth**.  Don't re-invent the wheel.  Crypto and security are _hard_, and it looks like you aren't ready for them yet.

Comment: you could say that Crypto and Security are a PITA. ;)

Comment: Well, I am a newbie programmer -_-#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't encrypt it.  When a user initiates a password reset, put a random token into their user details (if you have a database, that is).  Validate against that token.  Once the password has successfully been reset, eliminate that token from the db.

Comment: +1 This in combination with the exact timestamp should be enough it seems. Both can be passed in the link.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include a keyed hash to prevent attackers from substituting other user IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't show the UserId in the query string.

You could keep a record of password resets in your database. Create a hash and assign it to a UserId, SendDate, ExpiryDate, and whatever else you need.

Send the hash on the query string instead, and when you receive the request, look up the details associated with it.